# Como deixar um campo para selecionar nomes em ordem alfabética

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

Gostaria de saber se tem alguma função própria do typescript ou javascript que realize essa organização em ordem alfabética. se sim qual e como usa-la

Answer (score 1):

Se você quer criar uma caixa de seleção com nomes em ordem alfabética, pode utilizar um array.  Você pode ordenar um array em ordem alfabética utilizando o método sort. Aqui tem um exemplo:

```js
var vetor = Array ('Azul', 'Amarelo', 'Vermelho', 'Preto');
var vetor_ordenado = vetor.sort();

// Para criar um campo com este array, você faria isto:
var dropdown = document.getElementById("meu_campo");

// Fazendo loop no array
for (var i = 0; i < vetor_ordenado.length; ++i) {
    //Adicionando novos itens
    dropdown[dropdown.length] = new Option(vetor_ordenado[i], vetor_ordenado[i]);
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <select id="meu_campo">
    <option>Selecione...</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, ja tenho um campo e so preciso deixa-lo em ordem alfabética.

Comment: @mateussantana Uai, é só você popular o campo utilizando a técnica que o colega te ensinou. Se o seu campo é estático, então faça a ordenação manualmente e voalá! PS: se quer algo mais específico, considere editar sua pergunta e adicionar mais detalhes. Abração!